# Show loading gif when downloading pdf

Tags: pdf, download, loading, gif

I have a pdf file served via regular html ('a' tag) but it can take a while to download on slow connections, is it possible to add a loading gif so the user knows that something is being downloaded instead of staring at the same page and maybe think nothing is happening?

I tried one of the solutions offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228673/how-to-show-loading-screen-before-pdf-document) to preload the pdf and store it in the cache until it is requested, it shows no loading image but the file should load faster:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
<!-- 
var pdfLoader = document.getElementById("pdfLoader");
pdfLoader.src = "http://mysite.com/mypdf.pdf";
//-->
//]]>
```

I'm on a decent connection so I have no way of testing it, should that work as it is or is there another option I can try?

Thank you.

Comment: Same issue - would like to relocate the pdf loading gif to the top of the load, by default it is at the bottom and out of view unless the user scrolls